# Compare Time in Tibco BW

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

How can I compare a particular time on every execution in Tibco BW everyday? There would be scenarios when we want to check a particular time of the day to proceed with the execution of a process.

Comment: Could you specify the Tibco BW version you're using?

Comment: 5.x is the version, that time, i believe 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a process everyday periodically, use a timer starter. To compare time on every execution execution you can use the following XPATH on desired condition.

```
(tib:compare-time(
tib:parse-time("HH:mm ss",tib:format-time("HH:mm ss",'10:30:00')),
tib:parse-time("HH:mm ss", tib:format-dateTime('HH:mm ss',current-dateTime())))='0' | '-1')
```